# Sourcing a file in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am running a SparkR application. I have an R script which initializes the SparkR. I need to use a function in other file as we do in normal R language.When I call the source("filename"), it says file not found. How to call the file ?

Comment: Please provide the commands you are using

Answer (score 0):

If you have to load a csv file in spark 2.1.0,you can use the following syntax,

df <- read.df(path="",source="com.databricks.spark.csv")